# php mysql chat autoload not working b/c can't get get chat id

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chat

so i'm trying to create a php mysql chat and i'm having success with the javascript load() on one page but on the actual chat page, i can't get it to work b/c each chat has it's on chat id (ch_id) attached to the URL (so it looks like chats.php?ch_id=#) ... when i try and auto refresh the chat window with load(), it doesn't bring over the chat id, so the page refreshed to blank. any thoughts?

CODE: HTML

```
<div id="load_chat">
  <?php include('load_chat.php'); ?>
</div>
```

PHP - load_chat.php file

```
<div class="scroller" style="height: 525px;" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
  <ul class="chats">
     <?php
        $chat = "SELECT * FROM chats WHERE ch_id = '".$ch_id."'";
        $r_ch = mysqli_query($con, $chat); 
        $w_ch = mysqli_fetch_array($r_ch);

        $get_chat = "SELECT * FROM chat_log WHERE ch_id = '".$ch_id."'";
        $run_chat = mysqli_query($con, $get_chat); 
        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_chat)) {

       $get_sender = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = '".$row_chat['u_id']."'";
       $run_sender = mysqli_query($con, $get_sender); 
       $row_sender = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sender); 

       $get_rec = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = '".$row_chat['r_id']."'";
       $run_rec = mysqli_query($con, $get_rec); 
       $row_rec = mysqli_fetch_array($run_rec); 

    ?>     
    <li class='in'>
        <img class='avatar' alt='' src='images/<?php echo "".$row_sender['u_img'].""; ?>' />
         <div class='message'>
         <a href='javascript:;' class='name'> <?php echo "".$row_sender['u_fn']." ".$row_sender['u_ln'].""; ?> </a>
         <span class='datetime'> <?php echo "".date("g:i a", strtotime($row_chat['chat_sent'])).""; ?> </span>
         <span class='body'> <?php echo "".$row_chat['c_cont'].""; ?> </span>
          </div>
    </li>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>setInterval(function() { ('#load_chat').load('load_chat.php'); }, 2000)</script>
```

to clarify ... the '().load() function is working ... but when it refreshes, it is losing the chat id (.com?ch_id=# on the URL) ... i guess my main question, is there a way to pass the chat id to a subfolder / file? the page refreshes specific pages (when a new chat group is started, a file is created that has the php / mysql query to get all of the logged chats) and i need to pass the chat id to those pages ... how do i do that?

thank you for everybody who has already chimed in ... i really appreciate all the help i get from this community!!

Comment: Is your sample javascript exactly what you have in your application? Because if so, (and I'm assuming jQuery here), you want to change it to `<script>setInterval(function() { $('#load_chat').load('load_chat.php'); }, 2000)</script>`, you're missing the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main PHP file, transfer the chat's id to JavaScript like this (best in the `<head>`):

```
<script>var chat_id = <?= $ch_id ?>;</script>
```

Now use

```
setInterval(function() { ('#load_chat').load('load_chat.php?ch_id=' + chat_id); }, 2000)
```

Comment: hmm ... i tried it and i'm getting the same result ... it just keeps blanking out the chat window

Comment: You probably need to add `$ch_id = $_POST['ch_id'];` to the top of `load_chat.php`

Comment: I figured it out ... essentially passing the id was kind of a pain in the ass ... i just set it up that every time a new "chat" was created, it just created a new file and table and have the file reading the new table created ... i don't know if it's the right way to do it ... but it's working thus far :) thanks @ChrisG for your help!!